# Filtering in rest doesn't work

Tags: rest, filter

I want to do a simple task, which is to get all the items where the title contains some value. I searched and found the I must use `substringof('value',Columnname)`. But still my rest query is not working.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list')/items/?$filter substringof('value',Title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing it wrong. You need to use `$filter=` to filter results.

Answer (score 1):

Install the OData Query Builder available (for free) in the App Store

https://store.office.com/odata-querybuilder-WA104051159.aspx?assetid=WA104051159

[image]
<sub>(source: [msecnd.net](https://az158878.vo.msecnd.net/marketing/product/42949674376/1dd86fea-3b4d-4c31-a364-d865efd6fb0f/ScreenShot1ODATAQueryBuilder.png))</sub>

iDOC